# Follow-up email on job which has been put on hold

Tags: job-offer, email, follow-up

The dream job I was offered was put on hold over a month ago - hiring manager not sure when the role will re-open and that I should look for other roles in the meantime but asked me to stay in contact. How should I write follow-up email to see if there's any update on the role and let him know that I'm still looking for a job and if he could point me to some of his industry contacts who may be hiring, without sounding too desperate.

Answer (score 1):

> Dear [whoever],
>   I just wanted to follow-up to see if there's any
>   update on possible roles in your company that I could fill.  I think that your company would be a perfect fit for my career goals.
>
> Thanks,
>   jonathanh.

Also, look the guy up on linkedin and try to friend him.  If that works then you have his contacts.